# compare file A to B and spot differences

Tags: text-processing

I have a file in txt format but it is big (converted to doc is around 100 pages) and I would like to compare it to a newer version of it, B.txt.
Is there a nice way to mark all the parts that are the same, so I could spot the differences?

Answer (score 4):

There are loads of "nice ways", from which you can pick according to taste:

- NeoVIM:

  ```
  nvim -d A.txt B.txt
  ```

  It's a TUI text editor, so in addition to marking the differences, it allows you to fold differences, edit one file into the other, do syntax colourization on the underlying files, and do all sorts of general text editing tasks (from processing lines with filters to search-and-replace with regular expressions).
- VIM:

  ```
  vimdiff A.txt B.txt
  ```

  As per NeoVIM.
- GUI VIM:

  ```
  gvimdiff A.txt B.txt
  ```

  As per NeoVIM and VIM, but the user interface is GUI not TUI.
- diff:

  ```
  diff A.txt B.txt
  ```

  A "glass TTY" difference tool, whose output for convenience one often wants to pipe into a pager such as `pager`, `less`, `most`, or `more`.  Use `-u` for "unified" format that has a different marking scheme to the default output format, and `-y` as stated in sebasth's answer.
- sdiff:

  ```
  sdiff A.txt B.txt
  ```

  Another "glass TTY" difference tool, whose output one again often wants to pipe into a pager.
- Kompare:

  ```
  kompare A.txt B.txt
  ```

  A GUI *file difference* viewer, which also allows one file to be edited, difference by difference, into the other. 
  This is the second job that `kompare` does.  The other is a GUI *diff file* viewer, i.e. a graphical viewer for the output of `diff`:

  ```
  diff -u A.txt B.txt | kompare -o -
  ```
- emacs ediff:

  ```
  ediff-buffers
  ```

  The emacs operating system has its own diff command.  I hear that it will get a text editor soon.  (-:
- xxdiff:

  ```
  xxdiff A.txt B.txt
  ```

  Another GUI difference tool, which also allows one file to be edited, difference by difference, into the other.
- Meld: Another GUI difference tool.
- Kdiff3: Another GUI difference tool.
- Guiffy: Another GUI difference tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the files using [**`diff`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/diff.1.html).

```
diff -u A.txt B.txt
```

For a side by side comparison (2 column) use `-y` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually ***manually** "mark all the parts that are the same"*, I've [compared a LOT of visual diff tools for Linux](https://wiki.dandascalescu.com/reviews/software/diffuse_-_the_one_best_visual_diff_tool_for_linux), and found only two that support manual aligning - Beyond Compare and Diffuse.

There's also a Windows tool that runs fine via wine, and supports manual aligning - Grigsoft CompareIt!.